# Mysql, insert query every monday and tuesday

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure something out in mysql with an insert query but I'm in no good luck, so maybe you guys can help me out?

I have a database table with 3 values: ID(ai), Date en Status.
I want to add date with the status 'test' on every Monday and Tuesday from today till end of the year. I want to create it in one time so no auto creation every month or something like that.

So normally I would create an insert query for every Monday and Tuesday that would mean a lot of work because I have to change the date in the query matching the Mondays and Tuesdays till the end of the year.

I there an insert query that can create on every Monday en Tuesday till the end of the year a new row with the data of that Monday or Tuesday and the value 'test' in the column status.

Normally I would use this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) VALUES ('2020-08-17', 'test');
INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) VALUES ('2020-08-18', 'test');
INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) VALUES ('2020-08-24', 'test');
INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) VALUES ('2020-08-25', 'test');
```

As you can see that would mean a lot of copy/paste work but maybe there is a quick insert query that can do the trick :).

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you generate this externally using some kind of scripting language? MySQL isn't the best at doing this internally.

Comment: Hmm yes I was thinking about that, but I thought maybe there was a quicker way with mysql.

Comment: MySQL, by extension SQL, has very weak scripting capabilities. It's meant to be a data store more than a compute provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) VALUES ('2020-08-17', 'test');
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) SELECT MAX(date)+1, 'test' FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table1 (date, status) SELECT MAX(date)+6, 'test' FROM table1;
```

Repeat from Then

Comment: Wow thanks! you are great!!! Just needed some little changes from my side, I added some values. but it works